# How can I random two fields using get_field?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In the code bellow Im displaying one Case using get_field(); on my startpage.
Know I wanna be able to random two fields(), using get_field('promoted_case') and get_field('promoted_case_two'); on the startpage.
When a person updates the webpage Its supposed to random the two fields...
How can I do that in my code?

```
<?php if ( $case = get_field( 'promoted_case') ) : ?>
<?php $link = get_permalink( $case->ID ); ?>

<section class="content row">

    <header class="dotted">
        <h2 class="centered uc feat-case-header"><?php _e( 'Featured case', 'vvt' ) ?></h2>
    </header>

    <article class="promoted_case">

        <div class="row case-header">
            <div class="twelve columns">
                <h2 class="single-case-header"><a href="<?php echo $link ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $case->post_title ); ?></a></h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row case-content">

            <div class="columns six push_six">

                <div class="frontpage_case_image">
                    <a href="<?php echo $link ?>"><?php vvt_post_thumbnail( 'contact_images', $case->ID ); ?></a>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="columns six pull_six entry-content">
                <?php echo vvt_trim_words( $case->post_content ); ?>

                <div class="frontpage_case_btn">
                    <a class="button" href="<?php echo home_url( '/cases/' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show all Cases', 'vvt' ); ?> <i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </article>

</section>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fields = array('promoted_case', 'promoted_case_two');
$field = $fields[rand(0, count($fields) - 1)];
if ( $case = get_field( $field) )
```